# Is there a standard method to replacing the DEAD in a Genetic Algorithm?

Tags: genetic-algorithm

My particular GA problem creates a large percentage of dead offspring.  In fact, each crossover or mutation has less than a 1% chance of producing viable offspring.

What is the best way to replace the DEAD????

Are there any known papers or texts that deal with this in detail?

Comment: ... Have you tried searching?

Comment: By "dead" do you mean they have a fitness of 0? What type of selection are you using? There's some debate in the literature about whether or not this general phenomenon is useful for evolution (look up "holey fitness landscapes" if you want to know more), but in evolutionary computation it can often be a sign that you haven't framed your problem in a way that is conducive to solving via incremental change (evolution relies on there being some sort of gradient to climb). Depending on your selection method, one simple option is to only allow viable offspring into the population.

Answer (score 0):

It's a genetic algorithm. It will start out slow, but will eventually start to flourish. Hopefully your fitness function takes into account the characteristics of this 1%. Give it time, it will evolve.

Think of it like the cambrian explosion in the evolutionary history of Earth. There were only single-celled organisms for a very long time until out of the blue multicellular organisms started popping out everywhere.

Give it time.